# Online poker game system with nodejs and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am working on a MMO poker game,
Currently the whole poker gameplay system would be handled by socket.io by calculating datas in database, the socket would listen to the client's emit and hit APIs to the database to calculate the cards' strength, pots, player's turn etc..., everything is being stored to the database after every action from player

However, i dont know if this is the good approach, some suggested me that i could calculate whole things in a socket functions, by collecting necessary datas from database, all actions triggred by players would be directly calculated by socket function and after the end of the game, the socket stores the result of the game to the database (there will be less processes in the database)

What are the pros and cons ? Which one will cause bottleneck ?

Comment: NEVER. EVER. use databases for real time games

Comment: @Bálint, can you provide more details ?

Comment: Databases are slow, putting data in them is slow, getting data from them is slow, you should use something made for these kind of messagings, like a socket server